# TS2552: Cannot find name 'PictureInPictureEvent'. Did you mean 'PictureInPictureEventHandler'?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15, versionupgrade

I have upgraded my Angular app to version 15 from 14.
After upgrade I am getting following errors
`Error: node_modules/preact/src/jsx.d.ts:1078:3 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'PictureInPictureEvent'. Did you mean 'PictureInPictureEventHandler'?`

And

`node_modules/preact/src/jsx.d.ts:1124:3 - error TS2344: Type 'TargetedPictureInPictureEvent<Target>' does not satisfy the constraint 'TargetedEvent<EventTarget, Event>'.`

Following are the config details

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "watch": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use TS 4.9+ w/ Preact v10.15.0. You can upgrade your TS version or downgrade Preact.

You can follow this link, for reference [link](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/4023)

Answer (score 4):

This issue is due to a version mismatch of TS and Preact.

After trying to update TS for different versions to check compatibility with Preact I was still not able to solve this.

What solved this issue for me was adding the following statement within "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json file.

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```